# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified : Wierd issue

Tags: vbscript, odbc, qtp

I am working on one .vbs file in which I am connecting to DB using below lines of code and than running some queries.

```
Set cm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cm.ActiveConnection = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server ="+sInst+"; UID="+sUID+";PWD="+sPWD
cm.CommandType = 1 
cm.CommandText = sSQL 
cm.Execute()
Set cm = Nothing
```

Strange thing for me is when I am copying these lines to QTP and run it from QTP, it's working fine.
But when running .vbs file (by double clicking and from cmd), it is giving me below error:

**[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified**

I've other machine on which it's working fine both the way. I tried my best to verify all the things in both the machine, but I am not getting it.

I appreciate any thought / help / suggestion.

Thanks.

**Quick update:**
As vbs is not working I tried googled and create batch file with below line:

```
C:\Windows\SysWoW64\cscript.exe //NoLogo filepath\xyz.vbs
```

And its working now.
So question is how run vbs using ODBC from **SysWoW64** and not from **system32**...?

Answer (score 6):

Processes on 64-bit Windows are either pure 32-bit or pure 64-bit.
By default 64-bit Windows is executing your vbscript in a 64-bit engine which cannot call any 32-bit DLLs.

64-bit VBScript will use 64-bit ODBC which will only be able to call 64-bit Oracle software (if installed).
32-bit VBScript will use 32-bit ODBC which will only be able to call 32-bit Oracle software (if installed).

As you have discovered the 32-bit versions of most built-in Windows programs are hidden away from view on 64-bit Windows. You have to explicitly run the 32-bit version of ODBC administrator or CSCRIPT yourself.
From what you describe, you seem to have 32-bit Oracle software installed and configured on your machine. 64-bit Oracle software usually needs to be installed and configured separately.

Comment: Thanks @Morbo for the help.

Now my question is is there a way spaecify to use ODBC 32 in below line of code.

**cm.ActiveConnection = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server ="+sInst+"; UID="+sUID+";PWD="+sPWD**
 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. You misunderstand. You get 32 or 64 bit ODBC AUTOMATICALLY depending on which version of CSCRIPT is running. If you want to force 32-bit ODBC in a 64-bit environment you must (explicitly) run your script in 32-bit CSCRIPT.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

Go to the following path:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad.exe
```

Double click and pop-up will be opened:

1. Go to System DSN
2. Add
3. Now Choose `Oracle` in `Oraclient11g_home 1`
4. Now one pop up again open with the following fields:

   Data Source Name:PQALN07 (DB NAME)

   Description: PQALN07

   TNS Service Name: PQALN07  (DB  NAME)

   User Id :  RISK  (Schema Name)
5. By adding above DSN your problem will got resolved.

Now run your VB code using macro and you'll get no error this time.