# Run script without wscript.exe

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft, alm

I am trying to run the ALM test suite from Task Scheduler by writing a VBScript.

My VBScript runs only when executed from command line:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wscript.exe "C:\RunTestSet.cls.vbs"
```

When I run the script directly I get an error:

> Unable to create an instance of the TestDirector API OLE.

I get different error when run through Task Scheduler:

> Task Scheduler failed to launch action "\SysWOW64\wscript.exe" in instance "XXXXXXX" of task "\UFT Test 2". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147942667.

Please help me to run this script from Task Scheduler.

I tried giving this in start in (without quoted): `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wscript.exe`

Comment: does this answer help? --> [use Vbscript with ALM’s OTA API and use Windows scheduler to run](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32592983/5090771)

Comment: I used the sctipt mentioned and exceuted, I am getting 'ActiveX comeponent cannot create object'. NOte: I am executing this on 64 bit machine

Comment: I would suggest create a batch file and write this line in it: `C:\Windows\SysWoW64\cscript.exe //NoLogo C:\RunTestSet.cls.vbs` and run that batch file. For more information on this pls see [**my question on same topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20227569/1652222)

Answer (score 0):

Since ALM is 32 bit and the OS you are using to execute is 64 bit OS.
There is a way to register the 64 bit compatible wsctipt.exe to diretly execute it as:
regsvr32 "c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Mercury Interactive\Quality Center\OTAClient.dll"

but you can directly call, 
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wscript.exe "C:\RunTestSet.cls.vbs"
for a 64 bit OS as you did above.